# Google API to Artifact library information

Tags: android, google-api

I am looking for an API to retrieve all the artifacts characteristics that I can see in the Artifact library on the Google Play console, such as the `version code`, `version name`, `type` and `uploaded` columns.

After some research in the [android-publisher API doc](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher) I could not manage to find what I am looking for.

Screenshot of the Artifact library with the columns that I am trying to retrieve:

[image: screenshot]